# Xamarin Forms: How to pass an access token to a WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, access-token

I have a website which uses an identity server to authenticate a user, though OIDC, I think. Inside the Xamarin Forms application, I have a facility to log in a user through an identity server via a token.

The website itself uses cookies to handle access tokens which difference to the application. (Note: the website was not written by me). I have so many features to write, so I decided to use WebView to handle those features using React, etc., so I don't need to rewrite the code in native and easy to manage at runtime when people using the application.

What is the logic behind having the mobile application log into the authorized page silently without the user needing to authenticate within the WebView?

Is it possible to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can use the `CookieManager` to add/remove cookies that your private instance of `Webview` will use.

On iOS, `UIWebView` has `NSHTTPCookieStorage` and on the newer `WKWebView` (11+) you have `WKHTTPCookieStore`